# Nested IF, And excel formula

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, nested

Unfortunately I'm not a programmer, just a guy seeking help from those much more familiar than I. I'm trying to write a formula involving two cells. There are 4 outcomes based on 2 possible entries in each cell. What I'm wanting is if Cell A is High and Cell B is High, output Star. If A is High and B is low, Horse. If A is Low and B is high, puzzle. If both are low, Dog. Here's what I have:

```
=IF((And(K2="High",L2="High",Star),IF(And(K2="High",L2="Low", "Horse"),If(And(K2="Low",L2="High","Puzzle"),If(And(K2="Low",L2="Low","Dog))
```

Can anyone fix it for me?

Thank you,

Chad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but the `()` were in the wrong place.

```
=IF(AND(K2="High",L2="High"),"Star",IF(AND(K2="High",L2="Low"),"Horse",IF(AND(K2="Low",L2="High"),"Puzzle",IF(AND(K2="Low",L2="Low"),"Dog,"""))))
```

Comment: Thank you Scott! I figured it was parentheses but couldn't figure out how to get it right. I did take out the comma after Dog and two of the parentheses to clean up that output, but perfect other than that. Thanks again!

Comment: @Chad - Glad to help, please consider marking as correct.  Hit the big green check beside answer.